# How to extract div tag

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm trying to parse a html file and I want to extract everything inside a outer div tag with a unique id. Sample:

```
<body>
  ...
  <div id="1">

    <div id="2">
    ...
    </div>

    <div id="3">
    ...
    </div>

  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Here I want to extract every thing in between `<div id="1">` and its corresponding `</tag>` NOT the first `</div>` tag.

I've gone through many older posts but they don't work because they stop when they see the first `</div>` tag which is not what I'm looking for.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Have you looked at something like this: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/Parser.pm

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like your problem is that you are trying to [parse HTML using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068).

Don't. Use an HTML parser. There are plenty on CPAN. I'm fond of [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath).

Comment: Hi. Thanks it works but the text returned by `$tree->findvalue( '//*[@id="container"]');` has words glued to each other that is there is no space between them. Do you know the fix ?

Comment: basically it is joining the html text lines with one another without any separator.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with the code you're trying to use.

Comment: @gameover — use `find` to get nodes instead of a string. Then you can should be able to get an HTML representation of the node you get (I don't know the methods for that off the top of my head).

Answer (score 2):

[Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) has rightly mentioned using an HTML parser to extract `div` content.  Here's one option using [Mojo::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.80/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $text = <<END;
<body>
  ...
  <div id="1">
Under div id 1
    <div id="2">
Under div id 2
    </div>

    <div id="3">
Under div id 3
    </div>

  </div>
Outside the divs
</body>
END

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($text);

print $dom->find('div[id=1]')->pluck('text');
```

Output:

```
Under div id 1
```